# UIImage in Theos Tweak on SpringBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, theos, cydia-substrate

Hi people at StackOverflow

I can't get my image to show up on my SpringBoard

in my Tweak.xm SpringBoard is hooked, my UILabel shows up but my UIImage won't show up...

For the UIImage I tried to follow this question [UIImage may not respond to imageWithContentsofFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725416/uiimage-may-not-respond-to-imagewithcontentsoffile)

But I don't know what `imageWithContents**Of**File` meant stated in the answer so I'm still stuck with this code:

```
 [basePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"layout/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.png"]];
basePic.frame = CGRectMake(21.0,0.0,320.0,98.0);
[self.viewThing addSubview:basePic];
[basePic release];
```

Can someone help me with this?

Also theos doesn't give any warnings or errors when compiling, it compiles and runs sucessfully

I tried

```
NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.png"]);
```

and I got output, but when I try to let it show up on my SpringBoard it just stays empty

Comment: did you try [basePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"pic.png']?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageWithConentsOfFile:@"layout/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.png"]);`  What does this say?

Comment: In the linked answer `imageWithContents**Of**File` was emphasizing the uppercase `O` versus lowercase `o`, which isn't a problem your code has.

Comment: @nhgrif thanks for your answer and erm... Where am I supposed to see the output? I tried deviceconsole but can't find it.

Comment: @santhu this is a tweak so I must keep that type of directory tree

Comment: @nhgrif found it! Unfortunately it returns (null)

Comment: If it's returning `(null)`, then it's not finding a file at that path.

Comment: @nhgrif nope pointed the file from the root (/) and then my output was '<UIImage: 0x19f823e0>' means it was found, right? But the pic still doesn't show up on my screen

Comment: Can you get `NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageWithConentsOfFile:@"layout/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.‌​png"]);` to return a value in the same execution of code that doesn't display the image?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, I tried instead of layout/ this `NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageWithConentsOfFile:@"/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.‌​‌​png"]);` and I got output... but When I give my pic the same props so w/o layout/ as well it won't show up

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path of the image as it appears in the filesystem, not as it appears in your project directory.

Instead of this:

```
[basePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"layout/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.png"]];
```

You would do something like this:

```
[basePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/stash/subject4stw/weatherspring/pic.png"]];
```

However, I would not recommend putting any resources in this directory. As far as I know, the names of the folders in ./stash are auto-generated, and therefore may change with time or the device using the tweak. A constant path which you know is commonly used would suit better, so that line would *now* look something like this:

```
[basePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Library/Application Support/WeatherSpring/pic.png"]];
```